# Ki Ein by Yonatan Shlagbaum

Tags: sources-mekorot, song-poetry

I was listening to song called [*Ki Ein*](http://mostlymusic.com/products/yonatan-shlagbaum-ki-ein) by Yonatan Shlagbaum.

Here are the words to his song:
He כי אין הקב"ה אוהב אלא למי שאוהב את ישראל וכל מה שאדם מגדיל אהבתו לישראל, גם הקב"ה מגדיל עליו

Where does this song come from and what do the words mean?

Comment: Literally? To my limited knowledge, "For God loves no one except someone who loves Israel, and as much as one increases his love of Israel, God also increases [his love] on him."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mesilas Yesharim 19](https://books.google.com/books?id=uZ08AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=%D7%9B%D7%99+%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F+%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%91%22%D7%94+%D7%90%D7%95%D7%94%D7%91+%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%90+%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99+%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%95%D7%94%D7%91+%D7%90%D7%AA+%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C+%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%9C+%D7%9E%D7%94+%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9D+%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9C+%D7%90%D7%94%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%95+%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C&source=bl&ots=YnX3-rGuxt&sig=atBohaMwQpX6pegQ6nevOt-Biqw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4nhfVfPyEMaXNrWwgfAJ&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%91%22%D7%94%20%D7%90%D7%95%D7%94%D7%91%20%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99%20%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%95%D7%94%D7%91%20%D7%90%D7%AA%20%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9D%20%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9C%20%D7%90%D7%94%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C&f=false)....................